# Storing date/time of Last Application Run

Tags: c#, variables, console-application

I'm working with a console application (C#) at the moment. What it does is pulls files from a database and stores them in their relevant folders on the C drive on a local machine.

At the moment, every time I run the console app, it pulls ALL the files from the database.

What I would like to be able to do, is each time I run it, It only pulls the files that were submitted since I last ran the console application. Currently, this is the linq statement that pulls the files from the database.

```
var titleObjects = ctn.Titles.Where(t => !t.Deleted && t.SubmissionState == 2 &&(t.Approved.HasValue && t.Approved.Value)).Select(t => t);
```

Ideally I'd like something like the following where the date and time of the last run of the application is stored somewhere:

```
var titleObjects = ctn.Titles.Where(t => !t.Deleted && t.SubmissionState == 2 && t.CreatedDate >= LastAppRun && t.CreatedDate <= DateTime.Now  && (t.Approved.HasValue && t.Approved.Value)).Select(t => t);
```

I'm unsure on how to go about achieving this. If anyone had any advice on it I'd be very greatful :)

Comment: When your application starts, get the current date/time and process messages between the "last" date/time and the current. Before the app exits, have it save the current time as the "last" (you can e.g. format the time to YYYYMMDDHHMMSS and save to a file). What part of it are you unsure about?

Comment: @Jon, I'm just unsure what's the best way to do it to be honest. At the moment (I haven't included it above) I have the app set to ask the user for the To and From date, however I would just like it to work a bit more seamlessly than that. I just wasn't sure how I would go about saving the "last" date/time within the app (without using a database) or if it was possible even.

Comment: Options I can think of: 1. Your own file at the location of your choice on disk. 2. `System.Configuration` 3. `System.IO.IsolatedStorage` 4. The registry 5. The database itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just create a table in the database and insert a record that contains the last run time. Then update retrieve the value from the record on each run and update it when done.

Or you could insert a record for each run, to keep track of when runs have occurred and select the record with the maximum date time on each run to work out when the last run was.

Comment: Hi @andynormancx..yeah I did think of doing this, I just wanted to get other opinions to see what would be the best way of doing it. Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: Well your only other options are to store the value locally in a file or in the registry. The database would seem the best place for it though.

Comment: I think you're right. It would probably be good to have a record of the times that the application was run too. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use app.settings for this. It's a bit easier to just create a value and set its value as

```
Properties.Settings.Default.lastRunTime = DateTime.Now;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

It's a lot easier when you use the application with or without database

You can also encrypt the settings. google for encrypt.

Answer (score 0):

What if your database will have several console clients? It looks like the storing of the LastAppRun is a client-side task.

You may serialize LastAppRun into a file and store it in IsolatedStorageFile.

Other (more ugly) option is to go for a registry key.

Comment: Multiple clients is easily dealt with the database solution. Have a column that contains an identifier for each client and store the identifier for each client in app.config

Comment: Hi Sergey, the console app will only ever be used by one person so there is no issue with several console clients.